# error while seding email from jenkins job

Tags: jenkins, groovy, pipeline, jenkins-groovy

```
'''
    //def email_message = "Sending email to .... ${email}"
    //echo email_message.toString()
    def email_response = mail (to: "${email}",
    subject: "Jenkins build:${result}: ${job}",
    body: "${result}: Job: ${job} \nMore Info can be found here: ${url}")
'''
```

This throws a error in the jenkins file as below

```
    Error when executing always post condition:
java.lang.ClassCastException: org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.EchoStep.message expects class java.lang.String but received class java.io.NotSerializableException
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.structs.describable.DescribableModel.coerce(DescribableModel.java:492)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.structs.describable.DescribableModel.buildArguments(DescribableModel.java:409)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.structs.describable.DescribableModel.instantiate(DescribableModel.java:329)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.DSL.invokeStep(DSL.java:305)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.DSL.invokeMethod(DSL.java:196)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsScript.invokeMethod(CpsScript.java:124)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor359.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:98)
    at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:325)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1225)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1034)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaClassSite.call(PogoMetaClassSite.java:41)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:47)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:116)
    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker$1.call(Checker.java:180)
    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.GroovyInterceptor.onMethodCall(GroovyInterceptor.java:23)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.groovy.SandboxInterceptor.onMethodCall(SandboxInterceptor.java:163)
    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker$1.call(Checker.java:178)
    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker.checkedCall(Checker.java:182)
    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker.checkedCall(Checker.java:152)
    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker.checkedCall(Checker.java:152)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.sandbox.SandboxInvoker.methodCall(SandboxInvoker.java:17)
Caused: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not instantiate {message=java.io.NotSerializableException: java.util.regex.Matcher} for org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.EchoStep
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.structs.describable.DescribableModel.instantiate(DescribableModel.java:334)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.DSL.invokeStep(DSL.java:305)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.DSL.invokeMethod(DSL.java:196)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsScript.invokeMethod(CpsScript.java:124)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor359.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorIm
```

I am not sure what exactly the error is . I can see there is some problem with the serialization , but I am not able to see what is the problem.